# Create an element on the clicked position?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an element on the clicked position, and I figured out the following code. But nothing happened when I click on the page, and no errors were found in the console, Why?

```
function create(event) {
  var i = document.createElement("img");
  i.setAttribute("id", "a");
  i.src = *imagefile*;
  i.position = "absolute";
  i.style.left = event.clientX+'px';
  i.style.top = event.clientY+'px';
}
document.addEventListener("click", create);
```

Comment: You did create the element, although you just never added into the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues

1. You're creating the element, but you're not actually adding it anywhere. You need to make sure to append it to the dom with [`document.body.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
2. `i.position` should be `i.style.position` as position is a CSS style.
3. A minor nitpick. The 'id' attribute should be unique on a page. Clicking multiple times will make this not true. It's simply not needed in this scenario.

```js
function create(event) {
  //Create the image
  var i = document.createElement('img');

  //Set the source of the image
  i.src = 'https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/styleguide/identity/firefox/guidelines-logo.7ea045a4e288.png';

  //Set CSS styles so it appears where you clicked (Top left corner)
  i.style.position = 'absolute';
  i.style.left     = event.clientX + 'px';
  i.style.top      = event.clientY + 'px';
  
  //Add it to the body of the document
  document.body.appendChild(i);
}
//Main event listener for clicks
document.addEventListener('click', create);
```

Comment: Yes, I added `var n = 0;` outside the function and a `n++` inside the function.